# QT5 Title bar obscures top row of buttons on Windows 10

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5, qt5.6

My PyQT5 application is working fine on Linux, macOS and some Windows PCs, but on some Windows 10 PCs the top row of buttons is obscured by the window frame / title bar:
[image: Obscured Buttons]

Not only are the buttons obscured, you have to click below the buttons in order to click on them, so the click locations appear to be correct but the buttons are shown above the click locations.

The buttons are created in a QT Creator UI file as follows:

```
<widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
 <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="0" column="0" colspan="10">
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="OpenButton">
```

Versions: PyQt 5.6.0, qt5.6.2 from Miniconda

Comment: This bug is reproducible of all Qt5.6+ not only with pyqt.

Comment: How do you add the buttons, do you use layouts?

Comment: @Arpegius is it fixed in 5.7+ or are you saying this is a live bug in QT since 5.6?

Comment: I use Qt5.10 and the problem still occurs on windows 10, but the problem i think is in display driver as it start happens after some windows update.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by @Arpegius, this turns out to be due to the Intel Graphics Driver (see [QT bug 62127](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62127).

The problem disappears if I configure the QT application to use my NVidia adapter instead of my Intel adapter.